# how to change the default path in ld.so

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I use ubuntu 14.10 and crosstool-ng-1.20.0 to create toolchain from host: x86_64 to target: i686,
I know glibc will create ld.so but i don't know how to change the default path in ld.so from "/lib, /usr/lib" to "/lib32, /usr/lib32".

1. I want to change the the default path from "/lib, /usr/lib" to my setting "/lib32, /usr/lib32" in ld.so on my target machine. (because I put every .so file in /lib32 for 32 bit library, and will put other .so file to /lib for x86_64 not i686)
2. I don't want to add someflag(like "-z nodeflib", "--rpath=dir") on host in compile time to change every binary's search path on target machine. I want every binary without using theses flags can use ld.so to find the correct library

Does anyone know how to do this?

ps.
I use crosstool-ng to make
gcc-4.9 linaro, 
glibc-2.20 linaro, 
binutl ...etc...

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not need to change the *default* path, but rather *add* paths to the configuration.

Depending on your system, `ld.so` is configurable with a file in `/etc`/, and possibly with files under '`/etc/ld.so.conf.d` or `/etc/ld.so.d`.  The manual pages for [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and [ldconfig](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html) are a good place to start reading.

Comment: Thanks for Thomas~ but in my case the method won't work. In my target system, we have no /etc/ld.so* in my target machine. in my target system we don't use ld.so.d to put additional path.

Comment: I know library will search dependency on:
1. DT_RPATH
2. environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH
3. DT_RUNPATH
4. From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache
5. In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib. 
But we don't want to change the env value and binary's cflag, so 1~3 method we won't use. And in my target system, we have no /etc/ld.so* in my target machine. in my target system we don't use ld.so.d to put additional path. so method 4 won't work.

so I still have to change the default path in ld.so on method 5.